# Changing the number of nodes on ssh cluster to improve time

Tags: python, ssh, slurm

I'm using ssh to run a python program on a cluster, the cluster is configured to accept jobs using slurm. The sbatch script to run the .py is:

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=cnn
#SBATCH --time=1:00:00 
##SBATCH --output=cnn.out
#SBATCH --ntasks=8 
source activate cnn
python3 cnn.py
```

I think the program is taking to long to finish so I wanna know if changing the number of nodes (4,16 or 32 instead of 8) can improve that.

Comment: There's no way to say without knowing what the program does.

Comment: Also, there are very few chances the program itself knows where it should run. You should start it with srun and the code should handle the MPI communication properly.